# Div event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I have in my project a window click eventListener and some click events on div elements. If i click on the div the click event on this div-element (correct) and the window click eventListener fires (not correct).

Can I bubble the div element that the window click eventListener do not fire the event?

For a better demonstration jsfiddle:

```js
window.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);

function onDocumentMouseUp(event){
  alert('dont fire this event on button click')
}

$('#button').on({
  click: function (event) {
  alert('button click event');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background: blue"></div>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: do you need to bind to `mouseup` on window? or `click`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` like this:

```
$('#button').on({
  click: function (event) {
        alert('button click event');
        event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried this and it doesn´t work. If I click on the button, the window eventListener fires.

Comment: do you need to bind to `mouseup` on window? or `click`?

Comment: I don´t know what you mean with bind, but I need the click eventListener on window. I need the other event only on the div-element.

Comment: You're specifying `mouseup` here `window.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);` instead of `click` `window.addEventListener('click', onDocumentMouseUp, false)`. If you use `click`, my answer will work. Consider accepting it if it does